# use strtok to separate an URL into 2 parts in C

Tags: c

Hello. I'm new to C. I want to separate an URL into 2 part split by the first "/" in C.

I have the code:

```
char *token1, *token2;
token1 = strtok("website URL here", "/");
token2 = strtok(NULL, "/");
```

the problem is, if the website is like: "www.foo.com/foo/" it works. I got "www.foo.com" and "foo"

but if the URL has more than one "/", for example, "www.foo.com/foo1/foo2/foo3/". How do I get "www.foo.com" and "foo1/foo2/foo3/"? I don't want make more tokens because I have no ideal how many "/" will be in the URL.

Thanks.

Comment: All the answers really helped. But I can only accept one. I selected the fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `strchr` to find the first index of `/`:

```
/* char *url; */
char *first_slash = strchr(url, '/');
```

Then, `first_slash + 1` is the rest of the url (it is `NULL` if `/` is not in the string).  If you want to deal with 2 C strings, then just set to 0:

```
*first_slash = 0;
```

Then, your domain is `url` and the rest is in `first_slash`

Answer (score 1):

[**strchr**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) would be a better fit for this task:

**Example:**

```
const char* url = "www.google.com/one/two";

char *path = strchr(url, '/');

char *domain = calloc(path - url + 1, sizeof(char));
strncpy(domain, url, path - url);

printf("domain: %s\npath  : %s\n", domain, path + 1);

free(domain);
```

**Output:**

```
domain: www.google.com
path  : one/two
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get next occurrence of symbol without modifying source string using strtok. Also strtok is a danger function, it's not thread safe.

Why don't use strchr instead?:

```
char url[] = "www.foo.com/foo1/foo2/foo3/";

char *host = url;
char *path = strchr(url, '/');
if (path != NULL) {
  *path++ = '\0';
  printf("host: %s; path: %s\n", host, path);
} else {
  printf("host: %s\n", host);
}
```

result:

```
host: www.foo.com; path: foo1/foo2/foo3/
```